# javascript object group by with different properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties, reduce

my question is simple,

My input is

```
[ 
 { department_id: '28', linear_meter: 6 },
 { department_id: '56', linear_meter: 19 },
 { department_id: '28', square_meters: 20.28 },
 { department_id: '56', square_meters: 18.28827 } 
]
```

And i want out a something like this :

```
      [
       {
         "department_id": 28,
         "linear_meters": 6,
         "square_meters": 20.28
        },
       {
         "department_id": 56,
         "linear_meters": 19,
         "square_meters": 18.28827
        },
       ]
```

i tried that, but the result is not exactly what i want

```
var result = arr.reduce(function (res, obj) {
            if (!(obj.department_id in res))
                res.__array.push(res[obj.department_id] = obj);
            else {
                res[obj.department_id].linear_meter += obj.linear_meter;
                res[obj.department_id].square_meters += obj.square_meters;
            }
            return res;
        }, {__array: []}).__array;
```

but the output is :

```
[ { department_id: '28', 
    linear_meter: NaN, 
    square_meters: NaN },
  { department_id: '56', 
    linear_meter: NaN, 
    square_meters: NaN } ]
```

Someone have idea ? 
I testing before +=

```
  typeof res[obj.department_id].square_meters !== "undefined"
```

but nothing change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the object may not have the item so you are adding a number to undefined. Easiest thing is just use Object.assign() to copy over the properties.

```js
var arr = [{
    department_id: '28',
    linear_meter: 6
  },
  {
    department_id: '56',
    linear_meter: 19
  },
  {
    department_id: '28',
    square_meters: 20.28
  },
  {
    department_id: '56',
    square_meters: 18.28827
  }
];

var result = arr.reduce(function(res, obj) {
  if (!(obj.department_id in res))
    res.__array.push(res[obj.department_id] = obj);
  else {
    Object.assign(res[obj.department_id], obj)

  }
  return res;
}, {
  __array: []
}).__array;

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach reducing to an object with `department_id` as keys , using `Object.assign()` to merge properties and then use `Object.values` to return final array

```js
const data = [ 
 { department_id: '28', linear_meter: 6 },
 { department_id: '56', linear_meter: 19 },
 { department_id: '28', square_meters: 20.28 },
 { department_id: '56', square_meters: 18.28827 } 
]


const res = Object.values(
  data.reduce(function(a, c) {
    const id = c.department_id;
    a[id] = a[id] || {}
    Object.assign(a[id], c)
    return a;
  }, {})
)

console.log(res)
```